# Remove button after if table data isn't empty?

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I'm not sure of a good way to do this but I want the "Signoff" button to go away if the Work Order has been signed off.

[image: imgur]

Form:

```
{% for item in component %}
<td>
 <input type='button' name='user_one' id='signoff_user_one' data-rowid={{ item.id }} data-signoff='signoff_one' value='Signoff' />
     {{ item.signoff_user_one.name|title }} {{ item.signoff_date_one }}
</td>
<td>{{ item.workorder_num_one }}</td>
<td>{{ item.notes_one }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I was thinking of using twig to do this.

```
{% if item.signoff_user_one %}
   <span style='display: none;'>
   <input type='button' name='user_one' id='signoff_user_one' data-rowid={{ item.id }} data-signoff='signoff_one' value='&#x2713;' />
   </span>
{% else %}
   <input type='button' name='user_one' id='signoff_user_one' data-rowid={{ item.id }} data-signoff='signoff_one' value='&#x2713;' />
{% endif %}
```

HTML it produces:

```
<td><input type="button" id="signoff_user_one" data-rowid="56" name="user_one" value="Signoff">
          Blockout Only April 10, 2014
</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>OK</td>
```

But this removes both Signoff buttons as opposed to just 1. I'm guessing its not checking just the individual row?

Is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: Instead of solving it on jquery you should prevent this on server side, while the loop is creating the DOM elements check if it must be shown or not

Comment: @G.Mendes Not sure if I understand what you mean, can you elaborate ? *Updated code with loop

Comment: What HTML does that produce?

Comment: Once you open this page you load the table data from somewhere to display it in HTML, during this process you should be able to select what is shown or not, unless your data storage has a table or object for each of the users then you will need to do the way you said

Comment: @DavidThomas Updated post to show you.

Comment: And how do you know if the job's been signed off?

Comment: @DavidThomas If the variable {{ item.signoff_user_one.name }} returns data then I know its signed off. I have some jquery(AJAX) and a php script that processes and updates the table for each row and sets the user id into the correct column.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you handle the "signoff_user_one" value

if it's always there, but is boolean(true/false) try:

```
{% if item.signoff_user_one is false %}
{# render nothing #}
{% else %}
{# render button #}
{% endif %}
```

if we should consider whether item.signoff_user_one is defined at all its:

```
{% if item.signoff_user_one is defined %}
{# render nothing #}
{% else %}
{# render button #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If its always there? Per row? Its not always there. When that particular column is empty in my table, it defaults to NULL for each row that hasn't been signed off. I'm using "is defined", "is false" isn't working and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for every item you are creating the same id for the input, you should not do this as ID should be unique.

```
{% for item in component %}
<td>
 {% if !item.signoff_user_one %}
 <input type='button' name='user_one' id='signoff_user_one' data-rowid={{ item.id }}    data-signoff='signoff_one' value='&#x2713;' />
{% endif %}
 {{ item.signoff_user_one.name|title }} {{ item.signoff_date_one }}
</td>
<td>{{ item.workorder_num_one }}</td>
<td>{{ item.notes_one }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're right, the row-id is unique for each row. I could have from 1 to 20 rows at a time PER checklist. The problem is when I use your code I get the same issue as before, it looks for whether there is a value in the first row, and if there is, then it doesn't display the button for ALL rows when it should just be that one row. I'm not sure how to make it check per row and only apply to one row.

Comment: you are calling this for each tr? you should watch the component list if it has the same values for all